# Неправильный вывод таблицы ASCII символов

Tags: c++, ascii

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня при выводе от 0 до 255 символы от 0 до 27 сначала выводятся, а потом моментально пропадают? При этом 28  выглядит так: `ode = 28 char = ∟`. Именно без первой буквы "c". Если выводить от 0 до 27, то все выводятся без проблем. Если от 0 до 28, то выводится только 28 без "c"[image: ,].

Comment: в диапазоне  0-32 находятся управляющие символы. Например, перевод строки или забой (backspace). Они не транслируются в один символ по определению

Comment: @KoVadim Я бы сказал - при выводе выводятся не как символ, а в виде определенной функциональности, а так - почему не один символ? Какой-нибудь Tab - тот же один символ? Или что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: я имел ввиду именно то, что управляющие символы не обязаны быть представленными в виде одного знакоместа

Answer (score 2):

Символ с кодом 27 (0x1B) это символ экранирования (escape character). Он не имеет собственного представления и производит какое-то действие вместе со следующим символом. Возможно, в вашем случае этим действием является очистка консольного окна или что-то подобное. Попробуйте вывести все коды, кроме 27. Думаю, что строчки с 0 до 26 не исчезнут, а 28 будет полностью (с "с").

Comment: Может это символ удаления? Когда нажимаете клавишу `DEL` - удаляется буква, на которой стоит курсор. Получается удаление стоит перед `c` в слове `code` и эта `c` удалятся. А если два удаления сделать? Может первое удалит другое, а может они оба удалят `co`?:)

Comment: @Sergey Зачем гадать, когда можно просто посмотреть в таблицу ascii-символов? Там указано, что чему соответствует каждый код :)